# Textarea with font-size:30px still autozooms when activated on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, textarea, zooming

As I understand it, setting a text input's `font-size` to a size greater than 16px, is supposed to disable the autozoom effect that happens when you activate the text input on a mobile device.

I set the `font-size` to 30px, but the autozoom effect is still there. Tested on Chrome, Safari, UC, Mercury, and Dolphin for iPhone 5.

Here's a live example: http://www.rouvou.com/pages/Stack%20Exchange. It's the comment field. (users have to cast a vote before they can comment)

Here's my full code:

**html**

```
<div id="new-comment-mobile">
  <div id="new-good-comment">
    <%= form_for(@good_comment, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :text, maxlength: "650" %>
      <%= f.submit "Post" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#new-comment-mobile {
  position: relative;
  textarea {
    line-height: 130%;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Why is the browser still autozooming? I don't really want to disable all zooming functionality...

Comment: At least to me, you didn't set the font-size to 30. Font-size is still 14px when you open developer tools in chrome to inspect the text area. The CSS is not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the iOS developer tools via USB on my iPhone, I can see that your `font-size: 30px` has gone through. The reason @user1273587 could not see this via Chrome dev tools is because your `@media` selectors only change the font size on mobile.

From my testing, the higher the font size, the less the device zooms in. At about 60px from my testing, the device does not zoom at all.

Comment: It's weird there's no way to just turn off the autozoom, but I guess this is a decent solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in head tag:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' >
```

and post the result. 
P.S. check the css link

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly that does, but while it prevents auto zooming, it also prevents manual zooming in, which I want to allow. Also, all my fonts and images are much larger than usual so the whole style's messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered defining @viewport and then add the zoom attributes to it. Please check this for more on [@viewport](http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/)